# unknown error handler name 'rosmsg'

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying the rosserial tutorials from the official site in ros melodic. While running the Serial_node.py I m getting this error :

```
[ERROR] [1598645013.553322]: Creation of publisher failed: unknown error handler name 'rosmsg'.
```

I m not even able to run basic serial examples. Please help.

The Serial_node.log:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/1b4d1d4083a07d0c03ffe92a84aa299c

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360537/unknown-error-handler-name-%27rosmsg%27/) by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-08-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> unknown error handler name 'rosmsg'

This was a [bug in genpy](https://github.com/ros/genpy/commit/4af014a7cf180d572fea719f695bcaa6acf08267); it is fixed in 0.6.13.

Try upgrading:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

> Error opening serial: [Errno 13] could
> not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13]
> Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Try adding yourself to the `dialout` group:

```
sudo adduser `whoami` dialout
```

and reboot (or reload permissions).

---

Originally posted by [reinzor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3601/reinzor/) with karma: 106 on 2020-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mhallak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3537/mhallak/) on 2021-02-09**:
Thanks so much!

**Comment by [Maxim Rovbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20328/maxim-rovbo/) on 2021-04-28**:
It seems that the same problem occurs in 0.6.15, downgrading genpy built from source to 0.6.14 helps.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-28**:
@Maxim Rovbo: have you reported this?

A comment on ROS Answers has *very* limited visibility.

**Comment by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) on 2021-04-28**:
I just ran into the problem and even just using the latest genpy source (git clone into my workspace) worked. It was commit acf8eb7e8cd464af6650619961d8ff3c4f4a6ac8 which should be 0.6.15 as far as I understand .. so maybe the root cause is something else? Anyway Im happy with the fix for now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-28**:
Reporting issues is typically more to help others, not so much for yourself.

And work-arounds are not scalable.

**Comment by [Maxim Rovbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20328/maxim-rovbo/) on 2021-04-28**:
Added an [issue](https://github.com/ros/genpy/issues/138)

**Comment by [surv](https://answers.ros.org/users/74426/surv/) on 2021-05-12**:
Might also have to blow out the build and devel folders and rebuild the workspace.